# Rohan's grandmother is five times his age. After 10 years from now, his grandmother will be three times his age. How old are they at present?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Rohan's grandmother is five times his age. After 10 years from now, his grandmother will be three times his age. How old are they at present?

Comment: Can we use algebra?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: OK, we have some solutions using algebra.  Now I know from experience that some problems like this are given to 5th-graders who do not know algebra.  But they can solve them anyway!  How do they do it?

Comment: @GEdgar - they post them on Mathematics SE and let other people do their homework for them. Then they grow up and become managers, who hire a bunch of fifth-graders to do their job for them. Sad...

Answer (score 1):

suppose Rohan's grandmother's age is $y$ and Rohan's age is $x$. Then you get:

$y= 5x$

$y+10 = 3(x+10)$

Substitute the first into the second,

$5x+10 = 3x + 30$

which gives
$2x = 20$ or $x = 10$

Thus, Rohan's current age is $10$ and his grandmother's current age is $50$.

$10$ years from now, they will be $20$ and $60$ respectively.

Answer (score -1):

Currently,
G = 5R ---- (1)

(Where G = Grandmom's age, and R = Rohan's age)

After 10 years,
G + 10 = 3 (R + 10) 
==> G + 10 = 3R + 30
==> G = 3R + 20 ---- (2)

Solving equations (1), and (2)...
5R = 3R +20
==> R = 10 ----(3)

Substituting (3) in (1), will give G as 50.

Therefore, Rohan is 10 years old, and Grandmother is 50 years old (Current ages)

Answer (score -1):

Assume the ages are integers, let $y$ be the current age of the grandma, and $y+10$ be her age in $10$ years time. Then $5|y$ and $3|(y+10)$. For this to happen $y=5(3k+1)$, with $y+10=5(3k+1)+10=5(3k+3)=3(5k+5)$. So we want $5k+5-(3k+1)=10$, so $2k=6$ so $k=3$. So Rohan's age is $3\cdot3+1=10$ and grandma's age is $5(3\cdot3+1)=50$.